# cant find file when using docker containers

Tags: python, docker

I have an application which reads configuration file:

```
config.read('/data123/config/conf.ini')
```

The file `conf.ini` exists in `/data123/config/`

When I'm running my application from command line, the application can find the `conf.ini` successfuly

I made a docker for my application, and when I run my docker, the application can't find the file.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

- Why is this ?
- How can I read configurations files from applications when using containers ?

  - I don't want to create new docker each time the config file changes
    and
  - I don't want to use environment variables, because I have a lot of values in the config file.

Comment: Have you copy your 'conf.ini' file to docker container ?

Comment: why do I need to copy it if i search the file in /data123/config/ ? I want to change the conf.ini file when I need to replace some configurations...

Comment: @Boom, can you please share your Dockerfile? It is important that you put all the project files and configurations in the container for it to access when it runs.

Comment: You can either use `ADD` or `COPY` command in the Dockerfile to place the required file in the image, eg., `ADD . /<My-Project>/`

Comment: There wont be a `/data123/config/` folder in container unless it is created. You can put the config in `data123/config`  in the project root folder,  `COPY . /app` will copy the `data123` folder into the container. Then you can read it like config.read('/app/data123/config/conf.ini')

Comment: The `docker run -v` option can also mount host files like config files into a container, but Docker cannot access host files at all without some option like this.

Comment: copy the conf.ini file while creating the docker will be problem - because each time I need to change values in conf.ini I will need to create the docker again, no ?

Answer (score 0):

run your docker with this command:

```
sudo docker run -it -v path_to_file_you_want_to_work_with:/app/data123/config/ your_docker_name
```

and the container will run and load the config file you supply at run time